# Pandas .to_csv taking long to save relatively large dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

My df is ~4 GB in memory, of float16 dtype columns. I am trying to save to a CSV file using pd.to_csv but it is taking excessively long for a not-too-large data frame.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try saving it as parquet file

Comment: set the `compression=None`

Comment: @eshirvana not working

Comment: @KarthikS still taking too long.

Answer (score 0):

`float16` is a pretty dense data type - each floating point number is stored in 16 bits, or 2 bytes.

Assuming the entire data frame is `float16`, that would mean your data frame has roughly 2,000,000 numbers in it.

By contrast, an ASCII character is 1 byte, and a floating point number of unspecified precision often requires many characters.

A quick estimate using pseudo-random numbers suggests that the average number of characters used to represent `float16` values in text is between 5.5 to 6 characters each.

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.mean([len(str(x)) for x in np.array(np.random.random(100), dtype=np.float16)])
5.68
>>> np.mean([len(str(x)) for x in np.array(np.random.random(100), dtype=np.float16)])
5.84
>>> np.mean([len(str(x)) for x in np.array(np.random.random(100), dtype=np.float16)])
5.57
```

So on average a dataframe of `float16` will require more than 3x more disk space to write as a CSV than the space it occupies in memory (remember each number would require a character or line delimiter, adding one to the character size of each recorded value).

For a 4 GB dataframe, you could easily be looking at a 12 GB CSV file without compression. Exactly how long such a file would take to write depends on many factors, including disk speed, compression options (compressing the file would reduce the amount of data written, but different compression algorithms have widely varying compression times).  Your process could also be competing for resources with something else happening on the machine, leading to a further slowdown.

---

"Excessively long" is subjective and could be anywhere from a few minutes (which seems reasonable for a 12 GB file) to days depending on your definition. There aren't enough details in your question to determine what, if anything, the problem actually is.